# RSPEC not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, configuration, load

I'm learning Rails from Hartl's guide (http://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages)

and cannot get

```
bundle exec rspec /spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
```

to work. This is what I get:

```
sixxy@matilda:~/Rails/sample_app$ bundle exec rspec /spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
/home/sixxy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load': cannot load such file -- /spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb (LoadError)
from /home/sixxy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /home/sixxy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
from /home/sixxy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
from /home/sixxy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
from /home/sixxy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
from /home/sixxy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

Not only do I get this error within the Rails app I'm trying to test, but I cannot run rspec tests on Ruby code that I was attempting elsewhere. I get the same errors, leading me to believe that it's an error with my system's configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
```

No `/` in front of the path, otherwise RSpec starts looking for the file in your root directory and not in the current folder.

Comment: Wow, I'm gonna go kill myself now. Thanks.